# Ошибка LNK2019 при вызове класса

Tags: c++, visual-c++, twitter

main.cpp

```
#include "Variables.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    ifstream fin(book_name);
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(fin), istream_iterator<string>(),\
        back_inserter(book_text));

    twitterObj.setTwitterUsername(userName);
    twitterObj.setTwitterPassword(passWord);

    twitterObj.getOAuth().setConsumerKey(APIConsumerKey);
    twitterObj.getOAuth().setConsumerSecret(APIConsumerSecretKey);

    twitterObj.getOAuth().setOAuthTokenKey(myOAuthAccessTokenKey);
    twitterObj.getOAuth().setOAuthTokenSecret(myOAuthAccessTokenSecret);

    twitterObj.oAuthRequestToken(Authorize_URL);
    twitterObj.oAuthAccessToken();

    twitterObj.oAuthHandlePIN(Authorize_URL);
    twitterObj.oAuthAccessToken();

    twitterObj.getOAuth().getOAuthTokenKey(myOAuthAccessTokenKey);
    twitterObj.getOAuth().getOAuthTokenSecret(myOAuthAccessTokenSecret);


    /*All this magic*/
    for (auto it = book_text.begin(); it != book_text.end(); ++it)
    {
        word = *it;
        count_word += word.size();

        if ((count_word >= 110) || (word[word.size() - 1] == '.'))
            stop_recording = true;

        TWITT.push_back(word);

        if (stop_recording == true)
        {
            //Sleep(StepTime);//step whis one hours
            copy(TWITT.begin(), TWITT.end(), \
                ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
            TWITT.clear();
            stop_recording = false;
            cout << "{"  << count_word << "}"\
                 << endl;
            cout << endl << "---------------------------------------"\
                         << "---------------------------------------"\
                 << endl;
            count_word = 0;

        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Variables.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <dos.h>
#include "twitterClient/include/oauthlib.h"
#include "twitterClient/include/twitcurl.h"
#include "twitterClient/twitterClient.h"

using namespace twitCurlTypes;

/*blue  variables*/
unsigned int count_word = 0, count = 0; 
unsigned long long StepTime = 1200 * 60;
bool stop_recording = false;
char tmpBuf[1024];

/*green variables*/
std::string word;
std::string book_name = "WarAndPeace.txt";
std::vector<std::string> book_text, TWITT;
std::string userName("Username");
std::string passWord("password");
std::string tmpStr, replyMsg;
std::string myOAuthAccessTokenKey("739431278752243712-XYOwFd5upQF3LYVNlzdT3gBVFVEFxnG");
std::string myOAuthAccessTokenSecret("saJ8K7QydWAWXqnMX2fULUD3kV0FpgL0E66s7QfQUJ99U");
std::string APIConsumerKey("7IuxqRSTXDuX10m5SqODWZUEQ");
std::string APIConsumerSecretKey("9LxNQg6pxfC1c7NdnawWW0UWugjs80GcLfrYluSg6rg6ZBPSOy");
std::string Authorize_URL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
std::string RequestToken_URL("https ://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
std::string AccessToken_URL("https ://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
twitCurl twitterObj;
```

Лог:

```
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall oAuth::setConsumerKey(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?setConsumerKey@oAuth@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) в функции _main War_and_peace   D:\проекты\War_and_peace\War_and_peace\main.obj 1
```

Может кто сказать где ошибка и как ее исправить.

Comment: Ошибку вам указали вполне конкретно: `ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall oAuth::setConsumerKey`. Что делать - линковать с нужной библиотекой (так ли это на самом деле в вашей мешанине буковок не понять).

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в том что вы используете метод `oAuth::setConsumerKey(const std::string&)` которого нет в скомпилированном файле библиотеки `twitterClient` которую вы используете. То есть такой метод есть в заголовочном файле, но почему-то отсутсвует в бинарнике. Возможно вы используете старую версию и надо пересобрать `twitterClient`.